# Parse and get result with special formatting with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm newbies and i started with BeautifulSoup and Python dev and i want to get a result in full text without any HTML tags or other elements that are not text.

**I did this with python:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.demo.com/index.php")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

# COMMENTS COUNT
count_comment = soup.find("span", "sidebar-comment__label")
count_comment
count_comment_final = count_comment.find_next("meta")


# READ COUNT
count_read = soup.find("span", "sidebar-read__label js-read")
count_read
count_read_final = count_read.find_next("meta")

# PRINT RESULT
print count_comment_final
print count_read_final
```

**My HTML look like this :**

```
<div class="box">
      <span class="sidebar-comment__label">Comments</span>
      <meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="Comments:115">
</div>


<div class="box">
      <span class="sidebar-read__label js-read">Read</span>
      <meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="Read:10">
</div>
```

**and I get this:**

```
<meta content="Comments:115" itemprop="interactionCount"/>
<meta content="Read:10" itemprop="interactionCount"/>
```

**I would get this:**

```
You've 115 comments
You've 10 read
```

Firstly, is it possible ?

Secondly, Is my code is good?

Thirdly, could you help me? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `count_comment_final` and `count_read_final` are tags as clearly seen from the output. You need to extract the value of the attribute `content` of the two tags. which is done using `count_comment_final['content']` which will give as `Comments:115`, strip off the `Comments:` using `split(':')`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.demo.com/index.php")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

# COMMENTS COUNT
count_comment = soup.find("span", "sidebar-comment__label")
count_comment
count_comment_final = count_comment.find_next("meta")


# READ COUNT
count_read = soup.find("span", "sidebar-read__label js-read")
count_read
count_read_final = count_read.find_next("meta")

# PRINT RESULT
print count_comment_final['content'].split(':')[1]
print count_read_final['content'].split(':')[1]
```

Comment: Almost done, it displays "Comments" and "Read" instead of "115" and "10".

Comment: use `split(':')[1]`. sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

`count_comment_final` and `count_read_final` are tag elements,
You can use,

```
count_comment_final.get('content')
```

This will give a output like this,

```
'Comments:115'
```

So you can get the comments count like,

```
count_comment_final.get('content').split(':')[1]
```

Same is applicable to `count_read_final`,

```
count_read_final.get('content').split(':')[1]
```